# less versus fewer

Tags: grammar

I know that the right way to say it is:

**1) It took him 1 year less three months to finish it.**

I wonder is it ever correct to say

**2) It took him 1 year fewer three months to finish it.**

Answer (score 1):

"It took him 1 year fewer three months to finish it" is incorrect, in American English.

"It took him 1 year less three months to finish it" and "It took him 1 year minus three months to finish it" are grammatically correct, but do not sound natural.

"It took him 1 year subtract three months to finish it" does not sound correct to my ear.

"It took him 9 months to finish it" sounds natural.

Comment: Or "three weeks short of a year" would work, too, if that was the amount of time in question. However, "three months short of a year" is a clumsy construction for what is, as you say, "9 months".

Answer (score 1):

No, the second version

**It took him 1 year fewer three months to finish it.**

is not correct.

**There were fewer than ten people in the Sanskrit class.**

**I owe you $500, less the $75 I lent you for that piece of junk you bought at the flea market.**

*Fewer* has a comparison embedded in it. It will usually be followed by *than*, but not always.

```
How many people were in the Sanskrit class, thirty?
-- No, far fewer.
```